# How to push data to JavaScript Object Literal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I wanted to push data in JavaScript object literal. But, not able to find anyway. I am trying the following code.

```
var wd = { item: [] }
wd.item = {
    country: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.location.country,
    state: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.location.city,
    displayState: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.location.city + ', ' + weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.location.country,
    data: [
    {
        date: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast[0].date,
        day: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast[0].day,
        high: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast[0].high,
        low: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast[0].low,
        text: weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast[0].text
    }
    ]
};
```

I am trying to use push() function, but I am getting error.

After adding one item, following is the result.

```
 Object {item: Object}item: Objectcountry: "India"data: Array[1]0: Object$$hashKey: "object:254"date: "4 Jan 2015"day: "Sun"high: "84"low: "66"text: "Partly Cloudy"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]displayState: "Bangalore, India"state: "Bangalore"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

But, I am not able to add new data after this. Can somebody help?

Following code is working now.

```
var wd = { item: [] };
var
                location = weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.location,
                forecast = weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast[0];

            wd.item.push({
                country: location.country,
                state: location.city,
                displayState: location.city + ', ' + location.country,
                data: {
                    date: forecast.date,
                    day: forecast.day,
                    high: forecast.high,
                    low: forecast.low,
                    text: forecast.text
                }
            });
            console.log(wd);
```

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: umm not really relevant to the problem, but why don't you make a temporary variable and store `weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item` in it? Will be much more readable.

Comment: As this question has exactly nothing to do with JSON, I've removed the `json` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second line of code overwrites the array at `wd.item` with a plain object. I assume you meant to add the object to the array.

```
wd.item.push({
  // your big object
});
```

---

As @MightyPork said, your code would be so much more readable if you use a variable to hold the targeted nested objects.

```
var wd = { item: [] };
var loc = weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.location;
var forecast = weatherData.query.results.weather.rss.channel.item.forecast;

wd.item.push({
    country: loc.country,
    state: loc.city,
    displayState: loc.city + ', ' + loc.country,
    data: [
        {
            date: forecast[0].date,
            day:  forecast[0].day,
            high:  forecast[0].high,
            low:  forecast[0].low,
            text:  forecast[0].text
        }
    ]
});
```